# Anime movie from the 90s, where characters fight monsters with supernatural/psychic powers?

Tags: story-identification, anime

This is a long shot, but I remember walking into a video tape rental store and saw this playing, but the attendant didn't know the name of the film. I only saw it for a few minutes, and it was a sub, so I couldn't catch names or any big details.

There's not a lot to go on, but from what I remember:

- It looked like a 90s "battle" anime
- The scene had the character, a male in his late teens to 20s, in an open vest and pants, flying about.
- He was being attacked (or attacking) by some giant monster or enemy
- He had either light blue hair that turned white, or white hair that had turned blue when he went all out
- It *looked* like they were using psychic (or primal energy-based) attacks, with the black lightning and "mini black hole" effect.
- The art design resembled that of the first *Fatal Fury* movie, with those muscled, but elongated bodies, focus on subtle shadows and slightly sharper lines and subdued, non HD colors recognizable in most 90s anime
- It was **not** a *Dragon Ball Z* film, *Akira,* *X*, *Dark Cat, Psychic Wars, Wicked City, Demon City Shinjoku, Betterman, Ronin Warriors, Evangelion, Teknoman, Bubblegum Crisis, Fist of the North Star, Geno Cyber, Basilisk, Shadow Skill, Lost Universe, Bao, Vampire Hunter D, The Soul Taker, Beserk, Bastard!!!, Yu Yu Hakusho, S-CRY-ed,* or *karas.*

I'm heavily *presuming* it came out in the 90s due to art style, but it *could* possibly be very, *very* late 80s or *Early* 2000s; went into the video store in 2001, I think.

Any have any suggestions as to what it could *possibly* be?

Clips or pictures of the character suggestions may be useful.

Comment: @Gwyn I'm sorry, you put an answer here? I'm not seeing it. Was it deleted?

Comment: They commented suggesting Dragon Ball Z, but must have deleted it after I pointed out that you'd already ruled out Dragon Ball Z in the question.